# Bonacich Centrality in Python

Tags: python, networkx, node-centrality

I'm trying to measure the Bonacich centrality of my network in Python.

I am currently using NetworkX and was not able to find the Bonacich centrality in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to calculate the Bonacich centrality.
I create an example of how you might implement it with python.
So the steps are:

1. create the adjacency matrix (A)
2. calculate adj= A * A
3. calculate the row sum
4. total sum
5. normalize the row sum by dividing by the total sum, and the indexes indicate each node's centrality.

[git repo with the full code](https://github.com/1shaked/Bonacich-centrality)

```
import numpy as np

import networkx as nx

# Create a sample graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)])

# Get the adjacency matrix
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
adj = A.toarray()
centrality = np.dot(A,A).toarray()
print(centrality)
# Calculate the sum of the elements in each matrix row and store the result in a vector.
row_sum = np.sum(centrality, axis=1)
# normalize 
total_of_row = sum(row_sum)

row_sum_normalized = row_sum * 1/total_of_row

print('Bonacich centrality sores are')
for index, el in enumerates (row_sum_normalized):
   print(f'index - {index} is {el}')
```

I know there is a way to calculate it with the eigenvalue decomposition and row operation. The result will be the same.

Comment: Is there a way to use that code, but ensure that it is taking into consideration weight?

Comment: I think you can modify the adjacency matrix afterward and add the weights